# How to exclude special pages from being cached (Varnish)?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am new to VCL rules.
I want to exclude special pages from being cached by varnish cache.

What I exactly want to do is exclude all urls from being cached that include a specific query string "query=(number between 1 and 100)"

This code works only for one specific query.

```
sub vcl_recv {
  # don't cache these special pages
  if (req.url ~ "query=100") {
          return(pass);
  }
}
```

I just want to be sure this rule should work for the whole range from 1-100, right ?

```
sub vcl_recv {
  # don't cache these special pages
  if (req.url ~ "query=[0-9]") {
          return(pass);
  }
}
```

or do i have to do it like this ?

```
sub vcl_recv {
  # don't cache these special pages
  if (req.url ~ "query=1||query=2||...||query=99||query=100") {
          return(pass);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Varnish supports curly braces, if it does, you should do something like:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  # don't cache these special pages
  if (req.url ~ "query=([0-9]{1,2}|100)") {
    return(pass);
  }
}
```

By the way, this regular expression matches "query=990". I don't know how your url is composed but you should add something to avoid that (if you really need to).

For example, if there are other params:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  # don't cache these special pages
  if (req.url ~ "query=([0-9]{1,2}|100)&") {
    return(pass);
  }
}
```

Or in case it's the last param in the url:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  # don't cache these special pages
  if (req.url ~ "query=([0-9]{1,2}|100)$") {
    return(pass);
  }
}
```

Comment: Varnish is using PCRE library.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Perl regex supports curly braces :)